# Python script utilizing pass for exception handling, pass doesn't seem to function properly

Tags: python, exception, mysql-python

I am working on a script that is going to back-fill Call Detail Records from our asterisk system into our MySQL logs database.  In the code below, I am trying to ignore the duplicate keys and continue onto the next row, however when this code executes all I ever see is the first row dupe warning then the script exits (example 2, below.)  Is there a an obvious error that's causing it to fail?

Forgive my poor python etiquette, I'm very new to the language.  My assumption is that even though pass might break out of an exception, the foreach loop doesn't survive.

**EDIT/NOTE**: This is also worth mentioning after I solved the problem of the exiting for loop: because I had a `finally:` block which closed the sql connection, the `finally:` block was being executed after the `except: pass` and closing the connection.  So in the above example, the `finally:` was still causing the program to abend.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -d

import csv
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb
log="Master.csv"

try:
        con = mdb.connect('1.2.3.4','abcd','efgh','ijkl')
        cur = con.cursor()

        #Inefficient way of getting row count.
        rcount = csv.reader(open(log, 'rb'))
        print "Number of rows in csv: %d" % (len(list(rcount)))

        #OK, real csv processing now.
        reader = csv.reader(open(log, 'rb'))

        iter = 0
        for row in reader:
                print "Row: %d" % (++iter)

                clid = row[0]
                src = row[1]
                dst = row[2]
                dcontext = row[3]
                channel = row[4]
                dstchannel = row[5]
                lastapp = row[6]
                lastdata = row[7]
                start = row[8]
                end = row[10]
                duration = row[11]
                billsec = row[12]
                disposition = row[13]
                amaflags = row[14]
                accountcode = row[15]
                uniqueid = row[16]

                insertstr= "INSERT INTO cdr_extended (duration,billsec,amaflags,start,end,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,dstchannel,lastapp,lastdata,disposition,accountcode,uniqueid) VALUES (%s,%s,0,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" % (duration,billsec,start,end,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,dstchannel,lastapp,lastdata,disposition,accountcode,uniqueid)
                cur.execute(insertstr)
                con.commit()

except mdb.Error, e:
        if e.args[0] == 1062:
                print "Dupe key on uniqueid: %s"  % (uniqueid)
                pass
        else:
                print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
                sys.exit(1)

finally:
        if con:
                con.close()
```

The output:

```
Number of rows in csv: 2696
Row: 0
Dupe key on uniqueid: 1342632723.8
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using string formatting with SQL queries.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - What's your alternative suggestion?  Someone mentioned sqlalchemy to me, but it seemed like just as much work to get that setup.  This was intended to be a quick-and-dirty script, in a controlled environment.

Comment: In order to protect against SQL Injection attacks, you should not be using String formatting but use the `cursor.execute(query, args)` method. Use it this way: `cursor.execute("... %s ...%s", (param1, param2))`. Note that we are passing the string to be formatted AND the params as two separate args to `cursor.execute`. Escaping will be done at the MySQLdb level. 
Cheers.

Comment: Why do you _assume_ what `pass` does instead of looking it up in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements)?

Comment: @LukasGraf - Fair question.  However, understanding what pass does in this context would not have helped me solve the true problem which Blender pointed out in the accepted answer: that I didn't have the try/catch inside the for loop.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco thanks for pointing that out!  The next time I use MySQLdb in python I will be sure to remember that (or, just take the plunge and use an ORM.)

Comment: @PeterGrace True enough. But you would've known what _won't_ work. And `break` and `continue` are documented in the section just above, and `try..except` also isn't far ;). A wise man once said, [In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). We all make assumptions when learning a new language. But when things don't work as you expect them to, it's time to quickly verify those assumptions. Anyway, glad you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `try...except` block only around the code that would cause the exception, which is in the `for` loop. I don't use `MySQLdb`, but something like this should work:

```
            try:
                insertstr= "INSERT INTO cdr_extended (duration,billsec,amaflags,start,end,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,dstchannel,lastapp,lastdata,disposition,accountcode,uniqueid) VALUES (%s,%s,0,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" % (duration,billsec,start,end,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,dstchannel,lastapp,lastdata,disposition,accountcode,uniqueid)
                cur.execute(insertstr)
                con.commit()
            except mdb.Error, e:
                if e.args[0] == 1062:
                    print "Dupe key on uniqueid: %s"  % (uniqueid)
                else:
                    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
                    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: By putting the try/catch in the for loop, it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is used in python in place of empty curly braces of other programming languages.

`if x>0:
    pass`

is equal to `c`'s:
`if (x>0);` or `if (x>0){}`

use `continue` to continue the for loop.

Comment: continue would only work if the try/except was inside the for loop, which it isn't.